# Synthetic Control (can be done iteratively?)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, inference, synthetic-controls

Let's say I want to test the effect of a treatment, and since seasonalities and other factors are too complicated to model I am using synthetic control.
In order to be confident enough that the relationship found between my donors and the treated unit is stable, I leave a period between training and treatment evaluation to test. This is:  I train in t-5 to t-3 and test in t-2 to t-1 and evaluate the impact of my treatment applied in t in periods t to t+2.

Now, the complication I found: let's say that **my treatment is not just one shot,** but it implies many steps. An example could be changing gradually prices of different products to evaluate the overall purchases. So units could be different supermarkets of a chain and I apply the treatment in one of those. Also, let's say **my consequent treatments will depend on the reaction of the treated people**. So it is not one shot but has many steps where part of the treatment is applied and I'm interested in evaluating each part.

The complication here is:

1. how can I evaluate the 2nd time I apply a treatment since my relationship with donor units changed? Estimating new relationships? But I assume here I have to give some time to adjust. How can you measure how much time you need, or when this new relationship is stable enough?
2. Since this is using many donors I cannot leave those outside of the experiment (it is costly for the business to not apply the treatment to all of them). So again I have a situation where the relationships are changing again.

A dummy solution would be:

1. to apply treatment step 1 to unit A and evaluate vs the rest
2. and then apply the same treatment to all of the donor units used before to compare and apply treatment step 2 to A and compare again.

But the problems with this:

1. as I mentioned the treatment depends on the particularities of the units, so I cannot apply the treatment applied to A to all the units in step 1 to compare in step 2. This might not be an issue since we can say that the treatment is not the particular treatment as values applied but it is the application of the model that calculates those values. Fair enough. But now...
2. these treatments are planned to be applied on no less than on a monthly basis (ideally weekly) so then using only one month/week to estimate the relationship among units it's almost impossible.

All the examples I see for applying synthetic control are tested only once (applied a treatment only once and only in one group). Is there any other way to evaluate the impact of the treatment when the operation requires multiple "steps" treatments?

Thanks.